# How to click item appeared after mouse click in pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I want to click the items after a click.

My code is:

```
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=r'C:\Wind\Wind.NET.Client\WindNET\bin\wmain.exe')
dlg = app['Wind']
app2 = dlg.child_window(title="MenuBar")
app3 = app2.stock
app3.click_input()
```

#Now a menu appear and I want to move the mouse pointer to the item 'US', then another menu appears and I want to click the item 'TSLA'

How to use `pywinauto` to do it?

Thank you.